# Render header (with separate MVC files) in home page MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, renderer

My 'Home' controller gets data and stores it all inside its `$data` array. This array will be passed to the view (the `setOutput()` method) and echo'ed there. Now I have a 'Header' controller that does the exact same thing as the 'Home' controller. Getting data, passing it to the header view, etc. How do I load my page header into the 'Home' view?

I tried to load the 'Header' controller into `$data['header']`, within my 'Home' controller, but it returns the entire header object (header controller class).

**Controller looks like this:**

```
class Home extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Stores data in data variable
        $data = array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'key' => 'value',
            'etc' => 'another'
        );

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('path/to/header');
        
        // Send data to view file
        $this->response->setOutput($data, 'home');
    }
}
```

**`setOutput($data, 'home')` method looks like this:**
I thought I might need to render the header object here in some way?

```
public function setOutput($data = array(), $route) {

    $path = explode('/', trim($route, '/'));
    $file = end($path);
    $incl = '';

    foreach ($path as $dir) {

        if ($dir != $file) {
            $incl .= $dir . '/';
        }
    }

    $incl .= $file . '.php';

    require_once(DIR_VIEW . $incl);
}
```

Comment: `$this->response->setOutput($headerData, 'header');` 
`$this->response->setOutput($homeData, 'home');`

If you wish to render the two pages individually, that would be beneficial. Otherwise, you should be utilizing any template engine here if you're interested in producing a complete page that contains a header, footer, and site content.

Comment: You have misunderstood the concept of MVC. A View must be able to access its own data, a controller should not do that for the view. Further reading: https://r.je/views-are-not-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will a lot is unkown what is behind your methods it is hard to answer. But i think the the problem for your question is:

Your mehtods dont have return type (string) they print the output directly.
At least this is what the `require_once` of a view file looks like.

If you want to keep this architecture, you may need to use output buffering with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_cean()` and so on...

```
   ob_start();
   $this->load->controller('path/to/header');
   $data['header'] = ob_get_clean();
```

What @Code4R7 seems also true to me. Seems like an unfamiliar usage of MVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This really helped me. I might agree my MVC structure is a bit unusual as it is. I may not want to use this in actual production. All I did was return an `ob_get_contents()` from the 'Header' controller, into the 'Home' controllers `$data['header']` array. Everything is rendering great.